# HTML5 audio in chrome not working on sever

Tags: html, webserver, html5-audio

I have the following HTML code which works fine when I open it using Chrome.  The problem is the instant I upload it to my website, it stops working.  Does anyone know a fix for this?

```
<audio id="speech" controls="controls">
<source src="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=es&q=hola" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: "Does not work" is not a technical term. What do you mean? That link doesn't look like an audio file.

Comment: I mean the audio no longer plays.  You can click on the link or try use in in a browser yourself to see that it works.  It just stops playing when hosted on a server.

Comment: anything in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome plays the file directly from the link for me. Try changing the type to audio/mp3. Also, your server might not be set up to properly serve mpeg. Try adding one of these to an .htaccess file in the same directory as the audio file:
`AddType application/octet-stream .mpeg

AddType application/octet-stream .mp3`